# Instagram following box scrolling via selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, instagram

I've a code for getting followers from a user on Instagram.But, i've some problems. First of all, sometimes it ends before reaching the bottom therefore i cannot get the all of the followers. Secondly, when i try to get too much followers after a while it takes too much time to scroll. How can i handle these two situations on python?

```
followers_panel = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]')
    last_ht, ht = 0, 1
    while last_ht != ht:
        last_ht = ht
        ht = self.driver.execute_script(""" arguments[0].scrollTo(0, arguments[0].scrollHeight);return arguments[0].scrollHeight; """,followers_panel)
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 60).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "_ab8w  _ab94 _ab97 _ab9f _ab9m _ab9p  _abc0 _abcm")))
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 45).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '(//div[@class="_aano"])')))
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 45).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="_aanq"]')))

    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 45).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '(//div[@class="_aano"])')))
    list_of_followers = list(map(lambda x: x.text, self.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="_aano"]//a/span/div')))
```

Comment: did you try by deleting users from the HTML instead of scrolling?

Comment: I fixed the problem thank you. But now i have another problem. I got limited by instagram frequently. Is there a way to avoid this?